# How can I remove the EXIF tags/metadata from several images at once?

Tags: windows-7, photos, metadata, exif

I have a 6,000+ photos.  I want to remove a the tags from these photos.
I know how to do it one photo at a time. But wondering, what is the way to do mulitple files at a time?
Thanks

Answer (score 13):

You can do this easily with [**ExifTool**](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/):

```
exiftool -all= -overwrite_original -r .
```

This command will remove all supported tags from all supported file types in the current directory and all sub-directories. Be careful with this (remove `-overwrite_original` if you're not sure) and read the documentation first.

Comment: how do you specify the directory (with all of its subdirectories) in which the to-be-cleaned images are located?

Answer (score 4):

I personally prefer to use ExifTool as in Karan's answer but the issue with the command:

```
exiftool -all= -overwrite_original –r
```

is that it will also remove the color profile from the image if it exists.
If you prefer to preserve the color profile, use the following command:

```
exiftool -All= -TagsFromFile @ -ColorSpaceTags -OverWrite_Original –r
```

For an explanation of the command see [metadata - How can I strip tags from a JPEG without removing the color profile?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/56378/how-can-i-strip-tags-from-a-jpeg-without-removing-the-color-profile)

Answer (score 2):

[Exif Eraser](http://exiferaser.com) could do the job easily and is available with graphical user interface.

- ["Removing exif data from images"](http://www.ethow.com/2014/10/way-to-remove-all-of-exif-data-from-images.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a program like [ACDSee](http://www.acdsee.com/en/products/acdsee-15), which allows bulk operations.

I think [Windows Live Photo Gallery](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows-live/photo-gallery-get-started) (free) can do the same thing.